# Python arithmetic operation returns 0

Tags: python-2.7

```
read = True

while read:
    my_input = int(raw_input())
    print my_input
    result = (1/6) * my_input * (my_input + 1) * (my_input +2)
    if result == 0:
        print ''
        read = False
        break
    else:
        print result
```

I wrote this little code snippet to solve 1 + (1+2) + (1+2+3+)... without looping over anything but the result is always 0 for some reason. I am using PyDev on Eclipse but I do not think that's even remotely the issue

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integer division.

When you divide `(1/6)` it comes out to 0 because of integer division.

When two ints are divided, they come out to the normal answer, minus anything after the decimal point.

For example, 1/4 would usually equal 0.25.
However, everything after the decimal point is dropped, so it comes out to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying by zero always results in zero.

```
>>> a = (1/6)
>>> print a
0
```

This is happening because Python is casting the resulting operation to integer.

In order to get a float result you can specify the values in decimal notation.

```
>>> a = 1.0/6.0
>>> print a
0.166666666667
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I forgot it would try to convert 1/6 to int which is of course 0.

Comment: I just put the 1/6 at the end instead, for precision purposes